# less than or equal to condition is not working in my script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function ValidateAddOnModule(source, args) {
         var gdv = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContent_grdAddonModules');

         var j = 0;
         var k = 0;
         for (var i = 1; i <= gdv.rows.length - 1; i++) {
             var img = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContent_grdAddonModules_ImgLanUserError_' + j);
             var LANUser = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContent_grdAddonModules_txtAdditionalLANUser_' + j).value;
             var MinLANUser = gdv.rows(i).cells(2).innerText;
            // alert(MinLANUser);
           //  alert(LANUser);
             if (MinLANUser != " ")
             {

                 if (MinLANUser <= LANUser) {
                     alert("true");
                     img.style.visibility = "hidden";
                 }
                 else {
                     alert("false");
                     img.style.visibility = "visible";
                     k = 1;
                 }
                 j++;
             }
         }


         if (k = 1) {
             return false;

         } else
         {
             return true;
         }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What is ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContent_grdAddonModules here? Is it a table?

Comment: What values you are getting in `MunLANUser` and `LANUser` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var LANUser = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContent_grdAddonModules_txtAdditionalLANUser_' + j).value;
             var MinLANUser = gdv.rows(i).cells(2).innerText;
```

convert these to integer type.

```
     var LANUser = parseInt(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContent_grdAddonModules_txtAdditionalLANUser_' + j).value);

var MinLANUser = parseInt(gdv.rows(i).cells(2).innerText);
```

Answer (score 2):

frist try to change the numbers you grab from thext fields with `parseInt()` function

Comment: This'd be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

element.innerText will give you the output in string format. You have to first convert that value to integer using `parseInt`. Then only you can operate arithmetic operators on them.